# memory leak questions about c programming

Tags: c, memory-leaks

Will this function cause memory leak?

The function is :

```
double list(double *list2){
  double *list3=(double *)malloc(sizeof(double));
  some operations...
  return *list3;
}
```

update:

could this help?

```
int main(){

 operations...
 double list4;
 list4=list(&list4);
 free(&list4);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Prediction: someone is going to comment that you shouldn't cast the result from malloc.

Comment: What is the update supposed to help?

Comment: Could the free function in main free the space allocated in the list function? If not ,why?

Comment: That's going to crash because you're freeing the address of list4, which is on the stack, not malloced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does: it is returning a copy of the value of what is stored in the allocated memory, but the allocated memory itself is leaked (because the address has been "lost").

Comment: So this copy of the value is stored in the stack while i allocate it in the heap, so their addresses are different?

Comment: Of course; how could things in different places have the same address?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because you're allocating that double and not freeing it or returning the pointer (or making it accessible globally). Once the function returns, the pointer is lost, so it can't be freed.

Answer (score 0):

It will generate a Segmentation Fault since you are freeing a memory address  allocated inside a function.

As a result it allocation will be lost once function returns.